# Passing a dictionary to a template in azure devops yaml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to run a loop in a template to download two artifacts with specific versions.

I have been trying to formulate solutions for this but no luck yet, this is what I've came up until now but i think its not supported.

Can someone point me in the right direction if this is possible?

pipeline.yml

```
variables:
- template: project.variables.yml

jobs:
- job: 'Deploy'
  steps:
  - template: instantclient.template.yml
    parameters:
      artifacts:
        oracle-instantclient:
          package: 'oracle-instantclient'
          packageVersion: ${{ variables.oracle-instantclient }}
        oracle-data-access-components:
          package: 'oracle-data-access-components'
          packageVersion: ${{ variables.oracle-data-access-components }}
```

instantclient.template.yml

```
parameters:
- name: artifacts
  type: object
- name: feed
  default: ahitapplicationteam
- name: downloadDirectory
  default: deployment/s

steps:
  - ${{ each artifact in parameters.artifacts}}:
    - template: artifacts.template.yml
      parameters:
        packageVersion: ${{ packageVersion }}
        feed:  ${{ parameters.feed }}
        package: ${{ package }}
        downloadDirectory: ${{ parameters.downloadDirectory }}
```

artifacts.template.yml

```
parameters:
- name: packageVersion
- name: feed
- name: package
- name: downloadDirectory

steps:
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Downloading | Feed: ${{ parameters.feed }} | Package: ${{ parameters.package }}' #| PackageVersion: ${{ parameters.packageVersion }}
  inputs:
    command: 'download'
    downloadDirectory: ${{ parameters.downloadDirectory }}
    vstsFeed:  ${{ parameters.feed }}
    vstsFeedPackage: ${{ parameters.package }}
    vstsPackageVersion: ${{ parameters.packageVersion }}
    verbosity: 'Debug'
```

Comment: you could define `artifacts` parameter as an array. also when you're doing `${{ each artifact in parameters.artifacts }}`, you can access the object like that: `${{ artifact.package }}`.

Comment: I mean an `object` type could also be an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. You need to add the `-` character to each item in your `object` to convert it into an array. The `object` can be an array of simple strings or complex objects. As an `object`, you can access the properties of your objects in the `each` loop.

The use of `${{ variables.oracle-data-access-components }}` assumes that the `oracle-data-access-components` variable is available at *compile-time* when the pipeline is initially processed.

Whether you want to break it into 3 templates is a stylistic decision. I went with 2 templates to simplify readability, but a third template will provide you will some validation for required parameters.

pipeline.yml

```yaml
variables:
- template: project.variables.yml

jobs:
- job: 'Deploy'
  steps:
  - template: instantclient.template.yml
    parameters:
      artifacts:
        - name: 'oracle-instantclient'
          version: ${{ variables.oracle-instantclient }}
        - name: 'oracle-data-access-components'
          version: ${{ variables.oracle-data-access-components }}
```

instantclient.template.yml

```
parameters:
# list of package to download (name, version)
- name: artifacts
  type: object

# azure artifact feed name
- name: feed
  type: string
  default: 'ahitapplicationteam'

# download path for artifacts
- name: downloadDirectory
  type: string
  default: 'deployment/s'

steps:
# loop through the artifacts (name, version)
- ${{ each artifact in parameters.artifacts}}:
 
  # download the artifact
  - task: UniversalPackages@0
    displayName: 'Downloading | Feed: ${{ parameters.feed }} | Package: ${{ artifact.name }}' #| PackageVersion: ${{ artifact.version }}
    inputs:
      command: 'download'
      downloadDirectory: ${{ parameters.downloadDirectory }}
      vstsFeed:  ${{ parameters.feed }}
      vstsFeedPackage: ${{ artifact.name }}
      vstsPackageVersion: ${{ artifact.version }}
      verbosity: 'Debug'
```

Comment: Thank you @bryanbcook for the fast and constructive solution, that solved it. I was very close indeed.